# ssh session stuck after some time of idleness

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, fedora

I'm using fedora 19 and bash 4.2.53(1)-release

If I leave an ssh connection opened for some minutes and don't do anything with it, the terminal get stuck.

Here's netstat's output:

```
tcp        0   1440 x.x.x.x:port       x.x.x.x:port        ESTABLISHED 3596/ssh
```

So it seems that after some time the traffic just stays in the send queue and never leaves.

Any idea why? or what system tool/log should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shamelessly asked the question on serverfault as well. Here's the answer:

https://serverfault.com/questions/700855/ssh-session-stuck-after-some-time-of-iddleness